# search all values of list contains in a field of type string in mongodb and in mongodb java

Tags: regex, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-java

I have data in mongodb collection named speech with field id and speech in following format.

```
{ "speechtext" : "Always be a good boy" },
{ "speechtext" : "Always be a simply guy"  },
{ "speechtext" : "Always be a cute boy" },
{ "speechtext" : "I am a girl." }
```

I have to fetch data on behalf of two keyword like 'Always be' and 'boy' for the condition and,or,not.

if condition is 'and' for search with keyword 'Always be' and 'boy' result will be -

```
{ "speechtext" : "Always be a good boy" },
{ "speechtext" : "Always be a cute boy" }
```

if condition is 'or' for search with keyword 'Always be' and 'boy' result will be -

```
{ "speechtext" : "Always be a good boy" },
{ "speechtext" : "Always be a simply guy" },
{ "speechtext" : "Always be a cute boy"  }
```

if condition is 'not' for search with keyword 'Always be' and 'boy' result will be -

```
{  "speechtext" : "I am a girl." }
```

I have already solution for 'or' condition like below.

```
db.getCollection('speech').find({"speechtext" : { "$regex" : "Always be|boy"}})
```

I want query for 'and' and not' condition.

Comment: Please don't obfuscate `_id` values in sample data and rather just remove the non relevant data, which should also be a ready to "copy-paste" as possible to make it a usable and testable source. Also note your formatting was the wrong way around. Indented text is for code, and leave you paragraphs of "text" un-inindented. Also always check that your formatting is legible in this way before walking away from the post. Finally, if it really is a `regex` question, then tag it as such.

Answer (score 0):

Here are queries for 'or', 'and' and 'not' sequencially.

For or -

```
db.getCollection('speech').find({"speechtext" : { "$regex" : "Always be|boy"}})
```

For and -

```
db.getCollection('speech').find({$and:[{"speechtext":{$in:[/'Always be/]}},{"speechtext":{$in:[/boy/]}}]})
```

For not -

```
db.getCollection('speech').find({$or:[{"speechtext":{$nin:[/Always be/]}},{"speechtext":{$nin:[/boy/]}}]})
```